# Array sort with React.useState breaks when adding certain date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, sorting, date-fns

I'm trying to add a date in a list and sort that list to ascending every time I add a new date. Everything is fine, the list is being resorted when every new data is inserted, but if I start to add this date `13/02/22` the re-sorting will seem to have stopped and the new date inserts will be will just stack to each other/latest insertion will be the last regardless of its actual date.

[image]

Here is my code when adding a date to the list. And the `useEffect` in here is my sorting logic. As you can see I sort my list of dates by calling the `setAddedOpens` which is a React.useState.

```
const [addedOpens, setAddedOpens] = React.useState(defaultOpens);
 const [toggleSort, setToggleSort] = React.useState(false);

      const _addOpens = () => {
        for (let week = 0; week <= repeatWeeks; week++) {
          const OFI = new Date(getValues('OFIdate'));
    
          setAddedOpens((prevOpens) => [
            ...prevOpens,
            {
              ofi: format(OFI.setDate(OFI.getDate() + 7 * week), 'dd/MM/yyyy'),
              start: format(getValues('startTime'), 'hh:mm a'),
              end: format(getValues('endTime'), 'hh:mm a')
            }
          ]);
        }
    
        setToggleSort((toggle) => !toggle);
      };
    
      React.useEffect(() => {
        setAddedOpens([...addedOpens].sort((a, b) => new Date(a.ofi) - new Date(b.ofi)));
      }, [toggleSort]);
```

Don't mind the other parts of my code here. Because I also have a feature you can bulk add dates. But in the meantime let's say I'm just adding a single date every time I click ADD and that`repeatWeeks` state is always 0.

I'm not so sure what could be the problem is. Maybe I'm missing something in my logic? Or this has something to do with dates or date formatting? Why is the sorting getting erroneous once I added the date `13/02/22` ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The format dd/mm/yy is not supported by ECMA-262 so parsing is implementation dependent. Likely `new Date('13/02/22')` returns an invalid date so sorting fails. See [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add an additional property to the Object, let's call it `ofi_sorting`, that stores the date in the `yyyy-MM-dd` format and use that field for sorting the values:

```
    setAddedOpens((prevOpens) => [
      ...prevOpens,
      {
        ofi: format(OFI.setDate(OFI.getDate() + 7 * week), 'dd/MM/yyyy'),
        ofi_sorting: format(OFI.setDate(OFI.getDate() + 7 * week), 'yyyy-MM-dd'),
        start: format(getValues('startTime'), 'hh:mm a'),
        end: format(getValues('endTime'), 'hh:mm a'),
      },
    ]);
  }

  setToggleSort((toggle) => !toggle);
};

React.useEffect(() => {
  setAddedOpens(
    [...addedOpens].sort((a, b) => a.ofi_sorting - b.ofi_sorting)
  );
}, [toggleSort]);
```

Comment: This seems to have worked. Thank you. Let me do further test.

Comment: Thanks again. I'll use this solution. I guess what happened here is a bug in javascript dates?

Comment: Probably related to the fact that the `Date` constructor may interpret the first digit as the month using an `xx/xx/xxxx` format, depending on the locale. In general, when comparing dates, it is better to use the `yyyy-MM-dd` format.

Comment: I noticed I still have sorting issue. Though I eliminated the problem with the specific date in my post. I'll further investigate, but if you have something to add that would be really appreciated.

Comment: @LucaPizzini—while parsing of unsupported formats is implementation dependent, it is extremely unlikely that the system locale (by which you likely mean language) is used to determine the format of timestamps being parsed.

Comment: Incidentally, if the format is yyyy-MM-dd then there is no need to convert to Date objects, the strings can be compared directly as `(a, b) => a - b` or `(a, b) => a.localeCompare(b)`. :-)

Comment: @RobG, I have used localCompare instead of converting to Date objects. Thanks for this suggestion. If I just use `(a, b) => a - b` though I get erroneous results.

Comment: It seems I have fixed all issues now. So definitely I should avoid the `dd/MM/yyyy` format when comparing or sorting dates. All is working now I just need to refactor my code since this code `ofi: format(OFI.setDate(OFI.getDate() + 7 * week), 'dd/MM/yyyy')` will mutate the reference date and affecting my sorting. So I removed that and just reformat my date on render